Everyone has a soulmate except one man
I think I saw a trailer for this American movie/TV Show where there is a company which has developed an app/website that matches everyone to their soulmate. It turns out that there is an odd number of people in the world and there is one man who has no soulmate. 
I believe it was released in the last 5 years and it was a comedy.
For some reason I think it was a Will Ferrell - Will Arnett movie but I can't find it when I link to them.
Does this ring any bells? Can someone help me find this movie?

Hi. "saw a trailer" When? How old would you say it was? Was it American? What was the genre? (Comedy? Drama?)

@Walt, sorry this is my first question on this site. I added the details you mentioned.

Was it definitely a guy?...there's a movie Timer which has a soulmate app.

@Paulie_D I came across Timer when I was looking for this movie over the last 2 days. That seems interesting too but it's definitely not what I'm looking for.

It does star Will Arnett. This is the plot of The Seven Billionth Wheel, an episode from the first season of the YouTube Red sketch comedy web series Bad Internet from 2016.

Online dating's odd man out discovers an app that perfectly matches every person on earth, except him.

Arnett plays the company's CEO. Here's the trailer:




I love this website.
